# xpages djComboBox multival?

Tags: dojo, xpages

as far as I understand the tooltip, I only have to insert a multivalueseparator (",") and the combobox allows the choice of multiple values. 
But my doesnt. I looks like:

```
                        <xe:djComboBox id="djLType"
                            multipleSeparator="," value="#{user.LType}">
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.APrefs.UserTypes}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                        </xe:djComboBox>
```

applicationScope.Aprefs.UserTypes holds a text list like:

Owner|OW
Creator|CT
Controller|CO

On my xpage the combo box stays single choice, and it shows (that's fine) the text (Owner, Creator, Controller), but also stores the text, not the alias!

I must do sth wrong ...
Uwe

Comment: For three choices, I'd consider using a checkbox group instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the replacement for the usual Combobox is FilteringSelect component (the name is misleading). Dojo Combobox does not support label-value couples. Because it allows *any* input from the user (i.e. not bounded with the option list). If you use `djFilteringSelect` component, it will solve the first part of the problem.

Second one: Unfortunately, these components do not support multiple values. The option is there because almost all dojo components are inherited from the same template.

I recommend using **Dojo List Text Box** to hold multiple values. Combining it with a filtering select or value picker would be an effective way.

Comment: Thx Serdar - so I will use just an "ordinary" list box, I don't see any advantage of the dojo list box.

Uwe

Comment: Depends on what kind of user experience you need. I like dojo list box because it's a horizontal component whereas the usual listbox is vertical. It lacks selection (hard to select value) but good at deselecting. In usual listbox, the user has to know selecting multiple entries by ctrl key. On the other hand it allows better experience for keyboard-only use, etc. etc. :)